# Colouring markers based on value of another column - plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm currently writing a reporting dashboard for work and thanks to some changes in what is supported, my fancy and dynamic RShiny app is a no go so i'm trying to port it all over to javascript. I know almost no js, having written everything i know in python and R, and it is causing a significant head ache.

Problem:
I'm importing a csv and attempting to have dynamically produced graphs show a variety of things, coloured by a particular columns values.

So to keep it simple, (the real csv has almost twenty columns at this point and a few hundred rows of data) lets say i have:

```
#X.sample_id, key, project_type, manual_interventions
BulBa, 152, AAA, 12000
CharZard, 100, AAB, 5000
PikaChu, 117, AAA, 10
SquirTle, 090, AAB, 1000
```

Plotting `X.sample_id` as the X-axis, `manual_interventions` as Y and most importantly I need them to be coloured by `project_type`. Now i know this as easy as anything in python and R, the problem is that I don't want to produce a few dozen graphs to show variations of the same thing (there will be options for y-axis to be a fair few different things), especially when this can be done dynamically.

So far I have written:

```
<select onchange="selectedY()"  style="right: 10px; top: 20px;" id="dataBtn" title="Choose data">
    <option value="">Choose options</option>
    <option value="X.sample_id">TolID</option>
    <option value="key">GRIT Key</option>
    <option value="manual_interventions">Manual Interventions</option>
</select>

    <div class="card-body" id="chart"></div>
    <script>
        var data = [];
        var layout= {title: 'Graph', 'xaxis': {'title': 'X-axis'},
        autosize: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 500};
        var allRows = null

        Plotly.d3.csv('assets/data/pulled_data_sorted.csv', function(err, data){
                                        allRows = data
                                    });

        Plotly.plot("chart", data, layout, type="scatter", mode="markers");

            function selectedY() {
                var axisValue = $("#dataBtn :selected").val();
                var x_row = [], y_data = [];
                for (var i=0; i<allRows.length; i++) {
                    xrow = i;
                    row = allRows[i];
                    x_row.push(xrow);
                    y_data.push(+row[axisValue]);

                    var dataRow = {
                        x: x_row,
                        y: y_data,
                        mode: 'markers',
                        type: 'scatter',
                        line: {
                            color: '#62B5E5',
                            width: 2
                        }
                    };
               }

               layout['yaxis'] = {'title': {'text': axisValue}}
               Plotly.restyle('chart', 'y', [[]]);
               Plotly.plot("chart", [dataRow], layout, type="scatter", mode="markers");
              }
</script>
```

This produces:

[image: graph example]

Which is pretty far from the publication level it needs to be.

Admittedly, this was adapted from another persons work as i've found it difficult getting to grips with this, and i think there isn't much information showing any particular in-depth use of csv's and  plotly (maybe i'm not looking in the right place, i don't know).

So in the end I have no properly formatted X axis, I need to add an option to change the column of data X-axis uses, and no colour by project_type and I can't understand how to go further.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this now, i was relying on this working much like Python or R where colour is essentially figured out by the script rather than being explicitly given to it.

I'm aware this is still rough and i have alot to learn but i'm posting this in case it helps any future prospective js student.

```
<select onchange="selected()"  style="right: 10px; top: 20px;" id="dataBtn" title="Choose data">
       <option value="#sample_id">Tol</option>
       <option value="key">Key</option>
       <option value="manual_interventions">Manual Interventions</option>
</select>

<select onchange="selected()"  style="right: 10px; top: 20px;" id="dataBtn2" title="Choose data">
       <option value="manual_interventions">Manual Interventions</option>
       <option value="length change">Percentage Genome Length Change</option>
</select>

<select onchange="selected()"  style="right: 10px; top: 20px;" id="dataBtn3" title="Choose data">
       <option value="project_type">Project Type</option>
       <option value="'prefix">Clade Prefix</option>
</select>

<script>
        function selected() {
              makeplot()
        }

        function makeplot() {
              Plotly.d3.csv('CSV FILE',
              function(data){ processData(data) });
        }

        var layout = {
            autosize: true,
            width: 800,
            height: 800,
            xaxis:
                 {title: {text: "ID"}},
            yaxis:
                 {title: {text: "manual_interactions"}}
        }

        function processData(allRows) {
            console.log(allRows);
            var x = [], y = [], colour = [];
            var xaxis = $("#dataBtn").val()
            var yaxis = $("#dataBtn2").val()
            var colaxis = $("#dataBtn3").val()

            for (var i=0; i<allRows.length; i++) {
                 row = allRows[i];
                 x.push( row[xaxis] );
                 y.push( row[yaxis] );
                 colour.push( getColour(row[colaxis]) );
            }
            console.log( 'X',x, 'Y',y, 'colour', colour);
            makePlotly( x, y, colour, layout );
         }

         function rand_colour () {
             var r = Math.random()*255;
             var g = Math.random()*255;
             var b = Math.random()*255;
             return 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')'
         }

         var colour_map = {}

         function getColour(project) {
             console.log(colour_map)
             if (project in colour_map) {return colour_map[project]}
                 colour_map[project] = rand_colour();
                 console.log(colour_map[project]);
                 return colour_map[project]
         }

         function makePlotly( x, y, colour, layout){
             var traces = [{
                 x: x,
                 y: y,
                 type: "scatter",
                 mode: "markers",
                 marker: {
                          color: colour,
                          width: 2
                         }
              }];
              Plotly.react('chart', traces, layout, {displayModeBar: true});
         }

         makeplot();
</script>
```

This has resulted in the following being produced, it's not perfect but it is definitely much closer to what i need than before. It is coloured by the number of projects in use.
[image]